# Как сделать выбор компании аккаунта?

Tags: php, yii2

yii2-advanced, есть аккаунт, к нему нужно привязать id компании.

Проблема в том что я делаю это через update, который работает с моделью пользователей и моделью таблицы ролей, а в таблице пользователей уже есть метод afterSave, который присваивает пользователю роль user, и если при update я меняю только fabricators_id, но не меняю роль, то выскакивает ошибка `Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'user-5' for key 'PRIMARY'`.

Я понимаю что это за ошибка (попытка создать дубликат записи), но как ее обойти? Как оформить проверку ,было ли изменение роли или нет? Или afterSave срабатывает всегда?

Или лучше сделать 2 разных представления для смены роли и смены компании аккаунта?

actionUpdate:

```
public function actionUpdate($id){
    $model = $this->findModel($id);
    $usermodel = AuthAssignment::find()->where(['user_id' => $id])->one();
    if ($usermodel->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $usermodel->validate()) {
        if ($usermodel->save() && $model->save()){
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        }
    }
    return $this->render('update', [
        'model' => $model,
        'usermodel' => $usermodel,
    ]);
}
```

afterSave:

```
public function afterSave($insert, $changedAttributes){
    parent::afterSave($insert, $changedAttributes);
    $auth = Yii::$app->authManager;
    $user = $auth->getRole('user');
    $auth->assign($user, $this->id);
}
```

Form-view:

```
<?php echo $form->field($usermodel, 'item_name')->dropDownList(AuthItem::getParam('name')) ?>

<?php
echo $form->field($model, 'fabricators_id')->dropDownList(Fabricators::getParam('name'))
?>
```

Метод getParam (одинаковый для обеих моделей):

```
public static function getParam($param){
    return ArrayHelper::map(self::find()->all(), 'id', $param);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

afterSave срабатывает после каждого сохранения модели. 
Решить проблему Вашу можно так

```
if ($this->isAttributeChanged('role')) {
        // Что-то делаем
    }
```

Comment: да, это помогло, спасибо.

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста)